# Possible values for Autocleaninterval for APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";

Tags: cleanup

I want to set up autoclean on Ubuntu 14.04.

I found out that we can adjust the Autocleaninterval from "0" to "7" to do a weekly cleaning.

I wanted to confirm how I can adjust it to make it a monthly cleaning or daily should it be "30" or "1".

Comment: `monthly cleaning or daily should it be "30" or "1"` - yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to confirm how can i adjust it to make a monthly cleaning or daily should it be "30" or "1"

The option accepts days so of course it is 30. 1 would be arbitrary if it would not be 1 day since it could be 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year, 1 decade, 1 century.

Comment: okay. thanks :) I just wanted to confirm that it accepted in days so I can set it accordingly.

Comment: Just to confirm: here someone suggested to change the default to 14 or 28: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=511578

Comment: What does "0" mean?

Comment: @Flimm wheren set to 0 it is disabled.  Old behaviour iirc nowadays we use 7.